# Editing embedded components in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I got a PCB schematic and layout in Eagle format from a website and I want to edit the dimensions of components. Since everything is embedded inside the PCB layout and schematic, I find it difficult to edit component dimensions.

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Open the layout in Eagle and run the user language program `exp-project-lbr.ulp`. This can be done by clicking the ULP button and finding the file in the directory or simply by typing `run exp-project-lbr.ulp` into the command bar. This ULP comes with Eagle and the default selections work well so this should be all you need to do.

Run this by first clicking the `Collect Data` button then the `Create Library` button. Save the extracted library wherever you like. You can now edit the parts in this library.

Make sure this new library is in your library search path in the command window.

Finally, use the `replace` command to first select the edited part and select the old part in the layout to swap it out.

Comment: In more recent versions of Eagle the `exp-project-lbr.ulp` no longer exists, although it has been replaced by the `exp-lbrs.ulp` which meets the same need.